# C# what is causing this odd behaviour when accessing Static property in WPF main window from App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, static

I have the public static property "inDevMode" in the Main Window of my WPF project, I am setting this property based on command line params when starting the application.

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
if (startInDevMode)
{
    MainWindow.inDevMode = true;
}
mainWindow.Show();
```

The "MainWindow" within the curly braces is not highlighted grey (which the other two type references are) and when compiling I get this message:

> 'Window' does not contain a definition for 'inDevMode' and no extension method 'inDevMode' accepting a first argument of type 'Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I change what is within the braces to an instance reference (as below), which I know is wrong when accessing a static property:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
if (startInDevMode)
{
    mainWindow.inDevMode = true;
}
mainWindow.Show();
```

I get this error:

> Member 'MainWindow.inDevMode' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

But if I change the identifier of the "mainWindow" instance to "MainWindow" as below then I get no errors?

```
MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow();
if (startInDevMode)
{
    MainWindow.inDevMode = true;
}
MainWindow.Show();
```

and the type reference within the curly braces ("MainWindow") is now grey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MainWindow is a property of the `Application` class that returns a `Window` and this type has no "inDevMode" property. That's why you get the error. You have a naming conflict.

You could qualify the name of the `MainWindow` type with the namespace in order to be able to set the static property:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
if (startInDevMode)
{
    WpfApplication1.MainWindow.inDevMode = true;
}
mainWindow.Show();
```

Comment: But why would renaming the instance to "MainWindow" resolve the naming conflict?

Comment: Because then the name "MainWindow" suddenly refers to the local variable that is in scope rather than the property and then the name resolution succeeds. Please refer to the following link for more information about how the unqualified name resolution works in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711882(v=vs.71).aspx.